# Fetch data from model by relationhip belongsTo

Tags: ember.js

I would like to get data from my model by releationship one-to-one. Let's start with short description of my models

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    category_name: DS.attr('string'),
    phrase: DS.belongsTo('phrase')
});

App.Phrase = DS.Model.extend({
    phrase_name: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.belongsTo('category', { embedded: 'load' })
});
```

and handy code to fetch data in my ArrayController

```
this.get('model').filterProperty('category_id', 1);
```

This solution is not working. It is not returning anything. This effect takes place only when I am trying to find data by releationship, otherwise it is working fine. What I am doing wrong? The relationship is working well either, when I am displaying data.

All necessary data is already in model. I don not need to fetch it from server.

Answer (score 0):

It should be done like this

```
this.get('model').filter(function(item, index, enumerable){
    return item.get('category').id == category;
});
```